# Splitting line shapefile into segments of equal length using Python

Tags: python, shapefile, line, splitting

I want to split a line shapefile into segments of equal length, let say into lengths of x meters each. There is tool `v.split.length` as mentioned in this answer: [How to split line into specific number of parts?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116304/how-to-split-line-into-specific-number-of-parts) Is there a way to do that in python without using QGIS?

Maybe using shapely and Fiona? as there is an interpolate method in shapely which could be used to add points at a specified distance on a line. But I couldn't find a way to divide a line into segments of a specified length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a method using just ogr, it hasn't been tested extensively though. The split_line_multiple function takes an ogr LineString Geometry and returns a list of ogr LineString Geometries. Either the number of sub-strings or their individual length can be specified.

```
from osgeo import ogr
import math


def _distance(a, b):

    """ Return the distance separating points a and b.

    a and b should each be an (x, y) tuple.

    Warning: This function uses the flat surface formulae, so the output may be
    inaccurate for unprojected coordinates, especially over large distances.

    """

    dx = abs(b[0] - a[0])
    dy = abs(b[1] - a[1])
    return (dx ** 2 + dy ** 2) ** 0.5


def _get_split_point(a, b, dist):

    """ Returns the point that is <<dist>> length along the line a b.

    a and b should each be an (x, y) tuple.
    dist should be an integer or float, not longer than the line a b.

    """

    dx = b[0] - a[0]
    dy = b[1] - a[1]

    m = dy / dx
    c = a[1] - (m * a[0])

    x = a[0] + (dist**2 / (1 + m**2))**0.5
    y = m * x + c
    # formula has two solutions, so check the value to be returned is
    # on the line a b.
    if not (a[0] <= x <= b[0]) and (a[1] <= y <= b[1]):
        x = a[0] - (dist**2 / (1 + m**2))**0.5
        y = m * x + c

    return x, y


def split_line_single(line, length):

    """ Returns two ogr line geometries, one which is the first length
    <<length>> of <<line>>, and one one which is the remainder.

    line should be a ogr LineString Geometry.
    length should be an integer or float.

    """

    line_points = line.GetPoints()
    sub_line = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)

    while length > 0:
        d = _distance(line_points[0], line_points[1])
        if d > length:
            split_point = _get_split_point(line_points[0], line_points[1], length)
            sub_line.AddPoint(line_points[0][0], line_points[0][1])
            sub_line.AddPoint(*split_point)
            line_points[0] = split_point
            break

        if d == length:
            sub_line.AddPoint(*line_points[0])
            sub_line.AddPoint(*line_points[1])
            line_points.remove(line_points[0])
            break

        if d < length:
            sub_line.AddPoint(*line_points[0])
            line_points.remove(line_points[0])
            length -= d

    remainder = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
    for point in line_points:
        remainder.AddPoint(*point)

    return sub_line, remainder


def split_line_multiple(line, length=None, n_pieces=None):

    """ Splits a ogr wkbLineString into multiple sub-strings, either of
    a specified <<length>> or a specified <<n_pieces>>.

    line should be an ogr LineString Geometry
    Length should be a float or int.
    n_pieces should be an int.
    Either length or n_pieces should be specified.

    Returns a list of ogr wkbLineString Geometries.

    """

    if not n_pieces:
        n_pieces = int(math.ceil(line.Length() / length))
    if not length:
        length = line.Length() / float(n_pieces)

    line_segments = []
    remainder = line

    for i in range(n_pieces - 1):
        segment, remainder = split_line_single(remainder, length)
        line_segments.append(segment)
    else:
        line_segments.append(remainder)

    return line_segments
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, how to save the line_segments into shapefile?

Comment: Have a look at the answer given here:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129745/writing-a-shapefile-using-ogr-from-shapely-geometry-no-feature-added-error, or here: https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html#write-geometry-to-geojson (although change the driver to ESRI Shapefile instead of geojson).

Comment: how to convert the list of ogr wkbLineString Geometries (line_segments) to list of wtkLineString?

Comment: An ogr Geometry has a ExportToWkt() method which returns a wkt string, see here: http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Geometry-class.html

Comment: the segments produced by this method have 0 with the x ,y values in the Linestring like this: `LINESTRING (656772.081066615 -185004.101691471 0,656823.94704498 -185003.710250124 0,656861.329693538 -185004.101691471 0,656870.798486507 -184999.01659895 0)` any idea why we have these zeros?

Comment: You can use geom.FlattenTo2D() before you call ExportToWkt().

Comment: The `abs()` calls in your `_distance()` function are superfluous because `x**2` and `(-x)**2` are equivalent.

Answer (score 14):

Shapely can do what you ask. Here's an example of splitting a line string into 4 equal length parts.

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, MultiPoint
from shapely.ops import split

line = LineString([(0, 0), (10, 10)])
splitter = MultiPoint([line.interpolate((i/4), normalized=True) for i in range(1, 4)])
split(line, splitter).wkt
# 'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (LINESTRING (0 0, 2.5 2.5), LINESTRING (2.5 2.5, 5 5), LINESTRING (5 5, 7.5 7.5), LINESTRING (7.5 7.5, 10 10))'
```

It uses Shapely's [`interpolate()`](http://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.interpolate) to find the points at which to split. Shapely's [`split()`](http://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#splitting) function is new in version 1.6.0. This method is general and doesn't depend on the number of points that define your line or whether it bends.

In practice, `split()` is sensitive to the points being precisely on the geometry you want to split. Floating point issues might confound you in some cases.

Comment: I´ve tried this. It's awesome. :) BUT: How can i access the data of one member of the geometrycollection? For example, i would like to have the first linestring as an array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified shapely cut function for splitting a line into segments.

```py
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point

def cut(line, distance, lines):
    # Cuts a line in several segments at a distance from its starting point
    if distance <= 0.0 or distance >= line.length:
        return lines + [LineString(line)]

    coords = list(line.coords)
    for i, p in enumerate(coords):
        pd = line.project(Point(p))

        if pd == distance:
            lines.append(LineString(coords[: i + 1]))
            line = LineString(coords[i:])

            return cut(line, distance, lines)

        if pd > distance:
            cp = line.interpolate(distance)
            lines.append(LineString(coords[:i] + [(cp.x, cp.y)]))
            line = LineString([(cp.x, cp.y)] + coords[i:])

            return cut(line, distance, lines)
```

Some test 1

```
line = LineString([(6348053.180476057, 6652085.281694949), (6348206.3069751775, 6651979.8705129465)])
print(round(line.length, 4))
#185.9012
lines = cut(line, 30, list())
print([round(line.length, 4) for line in lines])
#[30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 5.9012]
```

Some test 2

```
line = LineString([(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 0)])
print(round(line.length, 4))
#5.0
lines = cut(line, 2, list())
print([round(line.length, 4) for line in lines])
#[2.0, 2.0, 1.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[`shapely.ops.substring()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#substring)** function. This cuts out one substring at an arbitrary location given by distance along the line. I use [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) to compute multiples of the distance. Then I apply Python's built-in [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to get the substring of the line for each pair of distances (combined by slicing appropriately). Since the line is always the same, I need [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) to feed it to `map`.

```py
from itertools import repeat
import numpy as np
from shapely import LineString
from shapely.ops import substring

def cut(line, distance):
    distances = np.arange(0, line.length + distance, distance)
    return list(map(substring, repeat(line), distances[:-1], distances[1:]))
```

Test slightly adapted from Grigory Nevsky's test:

```py
line = LineString([(6348053.180476057, 6652085.281694949), (6348206.3069751775, 6651979.8705129465)])
print(round(line.length, 4))
#185.9012
lines = cut(line, 30)
print([round(line.length, 4) for line in lines])
#[30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 5.9012]
```