# shapely split function does not work on short lines

Tags: python, shapely, splitting, multipoint

I am trying to split a line with multiple points. I adopt the solution in [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/255250/168805), but sometimes it does not work.

```py
from shapely.geometry import LineString, MultiPoint
from shapely.ops import split

line = LineString([(0.1, 0.01), (0.001, 0.001)])
splitter = MultiPoint([line.interpolate((i/6), normalized=True) for i in range(1, 6)])
gcline = split(line, splitter)
str(gcline)
```

The output is

```
'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (LINESTRING (0.1 0.01, 0.001 0.001))'
```

I guess it is because the line is too short. The method works fine for `LineString([(0.1, 0.1), (0.001, 0.001)])`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what happens.

check whether the point lies on the line

```
line.intersects(splitter[0])
False
```

It is because of float error. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50194077/shapely-unable-to-split-line-on-point-due-to-precision-issues, [Shapely floating problems with split()](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297134/shapely-floating-problems-with-split)

A good solution was provided by https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/327287/168805.